# Proper use of `isinstance(obj, class)`

Tags: python, class, isinstance

As I write it, it seems almost surreal to me that I'm actually experiencing this problem.

I have a list of objects. Each of these objects are of instances of an `Individual` class that I wrote.

Thus, conventional wisdom says that `isinstance(myObj, Individual)` should return `True`. However, this was not the case. So I thought that there was a bug in my programming, and printed `type(myObj)`, which to my surprise printed `instance` and `myObj.__class__` gave me `Individual`!

```
>>> type(pop[0])
<type 'instance'>
>>> isinstance(pop[0], Individual) # with all the proper imports
False
>>> pop[0].__class__
Genetic.individual.Individual
```

I'm stumped! What gives?

**EDIT**: My Individual class

```
class Individual:
    ID = count()
    def __init__(self, chromosomes):
        self.chromosomes = chromosomes[:]    # managed as a list as order is used to identify chromosomal functions (i.e. chromosome i encodes functionality f)
        self.id = self.ID.next()

    # other methods
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error indicates that the `Individual` class somehow got created twice. You created `pop[0]` with one version of `Instance`, and are checking for instance with the other one. Although they are pretty much identical, Python doesn't know that, and `isinstance` fails. To verify this, check whether `pop[0].__class__ is Individual` evaluates to false.

Normally classes don't get created twice (unless you use `reload`) because modules are imported only once, and all class objects effectively remain singletons. However, using packages and relative imports can leave a trap that leads to a module being imported twice. This happens when a script (started with `python bla`, as opposed to being imported from another module with `import bla`) contains a relative import. When running the script, python doesn't know that its imports refer to the `Genetic` package, so it processes its imports as absolute, creating a top-level `individual` module with its own `individual.Individual` class. Another other module correctly imports the `Genetic` package which ends up importing `Genetic.individual`, which results in the creation of the doppelganger, `Genetic.individual.Individual`.

To fix the problem, make sure that your script only uses absolute imports, such as `import Genetic.individual` even if a relative import like `import individual` appears to work just fine. And if you want to save on typing, use `import Genetic.individual as individual`. Also note that despite your use of old-style classes, `isinstance` should still work, since it predates new-style classes. Having said that, it would be highly advisable to switch to new-style classes.

Comment: `pop[0].__class__ is Genetic.individual.Individual` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: But what does `pop[0].__class__ is Individual` evaluate to in your interactive Python session where `isinstance(pop[0], Individual)` evaluates to False? (I should have been more precise in my answer.)

Comment: Yes, that evaluates to `False`

Comment: Then keep reading the answer... where I work we stumbled upon that particular problem many times in both testing and production.

Comment: That's some really weird behavior, but it seemed to fix it. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: I encountered this when using `isinstance` in a jupyter notebook after issuing the [`autoreload 2`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html) magic (which under the hood uses `reload` of course).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use new-style classes that inherit from

```
class ClassName(object):
    pass
```

From your example, you are using old-style classes that inherit from

```
class Classname:
    pass
```

EDIT: As @user4815162342 said,

```
>>> type(pop[0])
<type 'instance'>
```

is caused by using an old-style class, but this is not the cause of your issues with `isinstance`. You should instead make sure you don't create the class in more than one place, or if you do, use distinct names. Importing it more than once should not be an issue.

Comment: Could you post an explanation as to why this fixes the error? Also, my code was working yesterday, so I'm also interested in any other explanations you may have

Comment: Because inheritance doesn't work the same with old-style classes. With new-style classes, `isinstance` essentially checks `obj.__class__` and  then recursively each superclass found in `obj.__class__.__bases__`. With old-style classes, this behavior is not guaranteed. If we could see your definition(s), we may be able to explain why not in your case.

Comment: This answer doesn't even attempt to explain why `isinstance` fails for the OP. Using new-style classes would fix the `obj.__class__` vs. `type(obj)` discrepancy, but not the problem observed with `isinstance`, which is at the focus of the question.

Comment: This solution worked once. It failed on the second run. Weird